# Accessing a newly compiled program mid run

Tags: java, compilation, java-compiler-api, javacompiler

I'm using ecj for Genetic Programming and I have it built so it takes the best fit individual program after a run, and creates a java class with a function from the lisp code that is created.

I then have my program compile the java file. Is there anyway I can run the newly compiled class file in the same run?

I want to be able to:

RunMain --> Create Java --> Compile Class --> Call function in newly created class --> EndMainRun

So far, I'm having trouble calling the method in the newly created class.

Every time I create the new java file and compile, it rewrites the old one. But whenever that class is called later, it's running the old function pre-overwrite. Any tips would be much appreciated!

Edit: Here's some very basic pseudo code to show what I've got so far, a lot of it is abstracted. Assume that there is already a MathFunction.class file before I run this.

```
PseudoCode
Main(){
runGeneticProgrammingAlgorithm();
generateJavaFileFromBestFitIndividual(name = MathFunction.java) //Replaces old MathFunction.java
compile(MathFunction.java) //using JavaCompilerApi, replaces old MathFunction.class
double value = MathFunction.calculate(25);
```

The old function returned -1 for value, the new function should return 5, but it's still returning -1. Even if I put this all in a loop, it'll keep spitting out -1, -1, -1....

Edit 2:

I'm still having it return the same value despite the function being completely different. Here is the code:

```
    URL[] urls = null;

    File dir = new File("src" + java.io.File.separator + "ec");

    URL url = dir.toURI().toURL();

    urls = new URL[] { url };

    ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    Class cls = cl.loadClass("ec.MathSolution");

    MathSolution mathFunction = (MathSolution) cls.newInstance();

    System.out.println(mathFunction.calculate(123.5));
```

Edit 3:

Found an amazing source online here: http://www.toptal.com/java/java-wizardry-101-a-guide-to-java-class-reloading

Comment: show that file and the command series which you used so far!!!

Answer (score 1):

Achieving what you want to do is non-trivial but easily possible with some classloader magic.

The fact that you say 'it's running the old function pre-overwrite'... indicates that you are creating an instance of this class from the same classloader that you got it from the first time around.

I suggest reading up on ClassLoaders.

At a high level your algorithm should go:

1. Create java
2. Compile Class
3. Create a ClassLoader that is a child of your current
   classloader.
4. Load the class compiled at step 2 using this classloader
5. Instantiate the class or otherwise use it.
6. Now you see there is a new revision... start from 1

I will try to edit this answer with some code samples.

Comment: Yes! This sounds exactly like what I need!

Comment: Need me to elaborate with code samples? Or are you on your way?

Comment: It was late and went to bed last night. Going to tackle it now, and I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks

Comment: Hey Anup, I added some extra code above that I thought would reload the class for me but it doesn't seem to work. Any tips?

Comment: Found an amazing source for information here: http://www.toptal.com/java/java-wizardry-101-a-guide-to-java-class-reloading

Comment: Hey Anup, my attempts to work with that source didn't work out so well. Can you give me a little help?